# Patterns for implementing field change tracking

Tags: sql, database, design-patterns, change-tracking

For one of my recent projects, I had to implement **field change tracking**. So anytime the user changed a value of a field, the change was recorded in order to allow full auditing of changes.

In the database, I implemented this as a single table `FieldChanges` with the following fields:

- TableName
- FieldName
- RecordId
- DateOfChange
- ChangedBy
- IntValue
- TextValue
- DateTimeValue
- BoolValue

The sproc saving changes to an object determines for each field whether it has been changed and inserts a record into FieldChanges if it has: if the type of the changed field is `int`, it records it in the `IntValue` field in the `FieldChanges` table, etc.

This means that for any field in any table with any id value, I can query the FieldChanges table to get a list of changes.

This works quite well but is a bit clumsy. Can anyone else who has implemented similar functionality suggest a better approach, and why they think it's better?

I'd be really interested - thanks.

David

Comment: Just a note, recently I released my system to track changes as open source, you might want to check it tomcdc.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enterprise pattern for this is to have a amendment shadow table for every table you create to show the after-image (and possibly a before image) for all columns.
You will need:

- scripts to create the amendment table
- the triggers to populate them
- and maintain the above when the table changes over time.

But for a well setup enterprise all this should already be in place.

My organisation only uses this for the following:

- An audit for dbas and support to manually determine what happened (using SQL).
- Enterprise Data Warehouse (SAS) sucks all delta's from the production systems for analysis.

We create different tables if they are needed for the operational systems themselves.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!

There is the possibility of lots of duplication presumably as saves might only modify 1 field for example?

My experience of working with audit tables of this type is that querying them (e.g. to get changes to fields over a period of time) is a non-trivial task. :)

Answer (score 6):

Triggers.

We wrote a GUI (internally called *Red Matrix Reloaded*) to allow easy creation/management of audit logging triggers.

Here's some DDL of the stuff used:

---

### The AuditLog table

```
CREATE TABLE [AuditLog] (
    [AuditLogID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [ChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_AuditLog_ChangeDate] DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [RowGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL ,
    [ChangeType] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [TableName] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [FieldName] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [OldValue] [varchar] (8000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [NewValue] [varchar] (8000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [Username] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [Hostname] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [AppName] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [UserGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL ,
    [TagGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL ,
    [Tag] [varchar] (8000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
)
```

---

### Trigger to log inserts

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogInsert_Nodes ON dbo.Nodes
FOR INSERT
AS

/* Load the saved context info UserGUID */
DECLARE @SavedUserGUID uniqueidentifier

SELECT @SavedUserGUID = CAST(context_info as uniqueidentifier)
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@SPID

DECLARE @NullGUID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @NullGUID = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'

IF @SavedUserGUID = @NullGUID
BEGIN
    SET @SavedUserGUID = NULL
END

    /*We dont' log individual field changes Old/New because the row is new.
    So we only have one record - INSERTED*/

    INSERT INTO AuditLog(
            ChangeDate, RowGUID, ChangeType, 
            Username, HostName, AppName,
            UserGUID, 
            TableName, FieldName, 
            TagGUID, Tag, 
            OldValue, NewValue)

    SELECT
        getdate(), --ChangeDate
        i.NodeGUID, --RowGUID
        'INSERTED', --ChangeType
        USER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), APP_NAME(), 
        @SavedUserGUID, --UserGUID
        'Nodes', --TableName
        '', --FieldName
        i.ParentNodeGUID, --TagGUID
        i.Caption, --Tag
        null, --OldValue
        null --NewValue
    FROM Inserted i
```

---

### Trigger to log Updates

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogUpdate_Nodes ON dbo.Nodes
FOR UPDATE AS

/* Load the saved context info UserGUID */
DECLARE @SavedUserGUID uniqueidentifier

SELECT @SavedUserGUID = CAST(context_info as uniqueidentifier)
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@SPID

DECLARE @NullGUID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @NullGUID = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'

IF @SavedUserGUID = @NullGUID
BEGIN
    SET @SavedUserGUID = NULL
END

    /* ParentNodeGUID uniqueidentifier */
    IF UPDATE (ParentNodeGUID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditLog(
            ChangeDate, RowGUID, ChangeType, 
            Username, HostName, AppName,
            UserGUID, 
            TableName, FieldName, 
            TagGUID, Tag, 
            OldValue, NewValue)
        SELECT 
            getdate(), --ChangeDate
            i.NodeGUID, --RowGUID
            'UPDATED', --ChangeType
            USER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), APP_NAME(), 
            @SavedUserGUID, --UserGUID
            'Nodes', --TableName
            'ParentNodeGUID', --FieldName
            i.ParentNodeGUID, --TagGUID
            i.Caption, --Tag
            d.ParentNodeGUID, --OldValue
            i.ParentNodeGUID --NewValue
        FROM Inserted i
            INNER JOIN Deleted d
            ON i.NodeGUID = d.NodeGUID
        WHERE (d.ParentNodeGUID IS NULL AND i.ParentNodeGUID IS NOT NULL)
        OR (d.ParentNodeGUID IS NOT NULL AND i.ParentNodeGUID IS NULL)
        OR (d.ParentNodeGUID <> i.ParentNodeGUID)
    END

    /* Caption varchar(255) */
    IF UPDATE (Caption)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AuditLog(
            ChangeDate, RowGUID, ChangeType, 
            Username, HostName, AppName,
            UserGUID, 
            TableName, FieldName, 
            TagGUID, Tag, 
            OldValue, NewValue)
        SELECT 
            getdate(), --ChangeDate
            i.NodeGUID, --RowGUID
            'UPDATED', --ChangeType
            USER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), APP_NAME(), 
            @SavedUserGUID, --UserGUID
            'Nodes', --TableName
            'Caption', --FieldName
            i.ParentNodeGUID, --TagGUID
            i.Caption, --Tag
            d.Caption, --OldValue
            i.Caption --NewValue
        FROM Inserted i
            INNER JOIN Deleted d
            ON i.NodeGUID = d.NodeGUID
        WHERE (d.Caption IS NULL AND i.Caption IS NOT NULL)
        OR (d.Caption IS NOT NULL AND i.Caption IS NULL)
        OR (d.Caption <> i.Caption)
    END

...

/* ImageGUID uniqueidentifier */
IF UPDATE (ImageGUID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AuditLog(
        ChangeDate, RowGUID, ChangeType, 
        Username, HostName, AppName,
        UserGUID, 
        TableName, FieldName, 
        TagGUID, Tag, 
        OldValue, NewValue)
    SELECT 
        getdate(), --ChangeDate
        i.NodeGUID, --RowGUID
        'UPDATED', --ChangeType
        USER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), APP_NAME(), 
        @SavedUserGUID, --UserGUID
        'Nodes', --TableName
        'ImageGUID', --FieldName
        i.ParentNodeGUID, --TagGUID
        i.Caption, --Tag
        (SELECT Caption FROM Nodes WHERE NodeGUID = d.ImageGUID), --OldValue
        (SELECT Caption FROM Nodes WHERE NodeGUID = i.ImageGUID) --New Value
    FROM Inserted i
        INNER JOIN Deleted d
        ON i.NodeGUID = d.NodeGUID
    WHERE (d.ImageGUID IS NULL AND i.ImageGUID IS NOT NULL)
    OR (d.ImageGUID IS NOT NULL AND i.ImageGUID IS NULL)
    OR (d.ImageGUID <> i.ImageGUID)
END
```

---

### Trigger to log Delete

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogDelete_Nodes ON dbo.Nodes
FOR DELETE
AS

/* Load the saved context info UserGUID */
DECLARE @SavedUserGUID uniqueidentifier

SELECT @SavedUserGUID = CAST(context_info as uniqueidentifier)
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@SPID

DECLARE @NullGUID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @NullGUID = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'

IF @SavedUserGUID = @NullGUID
BEGIN
    SET @SavedUserGUID = NULL
END

    /*We dont' log individual field changes Old/New because the row is new.
    So we only have one record - DELETED*/

    INSERT INTO AuditLog(
            ChangeDate, RowGUID, ChangeType, 
            Username, HostName, AppName,
            UserGUID, 
            TableName, FieldName, 
            TagGUID, Tag, 
            OldValue,NewValue)

    SELECT
        getdate(), --ChangeDate
        d.NodeGUID, --RowGUID
        'DELETED', --ChangeType
        USER_NAME(), HOST_NAME(), APP_NAME(), 
        @SavedUserGUID, --UserGUID
        'Nodes', --TableName
        '', --FieldName
        d.ParentNodeGUID, --TagGUID
        d.Caption, --Tag
        null, --OldValue
        null --NewValue
    FROM Deleted d
```

---

And in order to know which user in the software did the update, every connection "logs itself onto SQL Server" by calling a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SaveContextUserGUID @UserGUID uniqueidentifier AS

/* Saves the given UserGUID as the session's "Context Information" */
IF @UserGUID IS NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Emptying CONTEXT_INFO because of null @UserGUID'
    DECLARE @BinVar varbinary(128)
    SET @BinVar = CAST( REPLICATE( 0x00, 128 ) AS varbinary(128) )
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @BinVar
    RETURN 0
END

DECLARE @UserGUIDBinary binary(16) --a guid is 16 bytes
SELECT @UserGUIDBinary = CAST(@UserGUID as binary(16))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @UserGUIDBinary


/* To load the guid back 
DECLARE @SavedUserGUID uniqueidentifier

SELECT @SavedUserGUID = CAST(context_info as uniqueidentifier)
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = @@SPID

select @SavedUserGUID AS UserGUID
*/
```

---

**Notes**

- Stackoverflow code format removes most blank lines - so formatting sucks
- We use a table of users, not integrated security
- This code is provided as a convience - no critisism of our design selection allowed. Purists might insist that all logging code should be done in the business layer - they can come here and write/maintain it for us.
- blobs cannot be logged using triggers in SQL Server (there is no "before" version of a blog - there is only what is). Text and nText are blobs - which makes notes either unloggable, or makes them varchar(2000)'s.
- the Tag column is used as an arbitrary text to identify the row (e.g. if a customer was deleted, the tag will show "General Motors North America" in the audit log table.
- TagGUID is used to point to the row's "parent". For example logging **InvoiceLineItems** points back to the **InvoiceHeader**. This way anyone searching for audit log entries related for a specific invoice will find the deleted "line items" by the line item's TagGUID in the audit trail.
- sometimes the "OldValue" and "NewValue" values are written as a sub-select - to get a meaningful string. i.e."

  OldValue: {233d-ad34234..}
  NewValue: {883-sdf34...}

is less useful in the audit trail than:

```
OldValue: Daimler Chrysler
NewValue: Cerberus Capital Management
```

**Final note**: Feel free to not do what we do. This is great for us, but everyone else is free to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by versioning. One version - one table row. Latest version - the row with the biggest last updated date.

Comment: Do you mean that the changes are kept in the same basic table as the data?

Does that not mean that your primary key isn't unique anymore?

Plus, when retrieving by ID, presumably you have to apply a WHERE clause to get the one with the last updated date?

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the trigger and let the trigger to automatically tracking the change and record them in your auditing table.